# Getting inputs num Sessions

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to get inputs num with Sessions. In order to get num of exact inputs I have code so far

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String pro=request.getParameter("inputs");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
    Integer Counter =
               (Integer)session.getAttribute("Counter");
    session.setAttribute("input", inp);
    if(Counter==null){
         Counter=0;
        println((String)session.getAttribute("input") +""+Counter);
    }
    if((session.getAttribute("input").equals(inp))){
        Counter++;
        println(session.getAttribute("input")+"" +Counter);
    }
```

Comment: Where should the output go?  Back to a browser or something else?

Comment: just servlet shows the output

Comment: shows to the user nowhere goes

Comment: @stdunbar I would highly appreciate if you help me

Answer (score 0):

I would do something a bit more like:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String word = request.getParameter("word");

    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();

    Integer numRequestsForWord = (Integer)httpSession.getAttribute(word);

    if( numRequestsForWord == null )
        numRequestsForWord = 1;
    else
        numRequestsForWord += 1;

    httpSession.setAttribute(word, numRequestsForWord);

    if( numRequestsForWord == 1 )
        System.out.println( word );
    else
        System.out.println( word + "(" + numRequestsForWord + ")");
}
```

This would require a POST - I'm not sure how you're calling this method.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar but I need it to show other values also in the same session. For ex, apple(2), juice(3), beans(5) like that

Comment: Are you theree?